# Как передать cookie с apollo-сервера на apollo-clenet

Tags: javascript, node.js, apollo-client

**Mutation**

```
Mutation: {
  signUp: (_, { res }) => {
    try {
      res.cookie("jwt", "token", {
        httpOnly: true
      });
      return "Amasia";
    } catch (error) {
      return "error";
    }
  };
}
```

**Apollo-clenet-react**

```
const [addTodo, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation(gql);

  const [formSignUp, setFormSignUp] = useState({
    lastName: '',
    firstName: '',
    password: '',
    email: '',
  });

  const change = e => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    setFormSignUp({ ...formSignUp, [name]: value });
  };
```

Когда я делаю запрос от реагировать. Вот ответ, который я получаю с сервера.

1)**Data**  `{"data": {"signUp": "Amasia"}}`

2) **Network**[image]

**Application**

Хорошо, когда я смотрю в Application Cookies, он пуст.
[image]

Что я делаю не так? Почему cookies пустые?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема в настройках apollo-клиента и apollo-сервера ([apollo-cookie](https://s3.amazonaws.com/apollo-docs-1.x/auth.html)).

Я настроил так.

**apollo-client**

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import './i18n';

import Loading from './component/loading';
import RouteProj from './router';

const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql',
  credentials: 'include'
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link,
});


render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <RouteProj/>
    </Suspense>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

**apollo-server**

```
import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

import schema from "./schema";
import resolvers from "./resolvers";
import models from "./models";

  const app = express();

  var corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true
  };
  app.use(cors(corsOptions));

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: schema,
    resolvers,
    context: ({ res }) => ({
      res
    })
  });

  server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: "/graphql", cors: false });
  app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```